# Toggle image and checkbox state on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQZfh/13/), here I have some rows in table which are disabled, I represent disabled by a lock. Right now if you click on lock then doc will be unlocked means checkbox will be enabled. I want that after this the lock image should be replaced with an open lock so that user can know doc is not unlocked. I need `toggle` option there like when user click on lock then image should be changed to unlock, and if user clicks on unlock image then it should be changed to lock and checkbox should get disabled.

I'm using `$( this ).remove();` to remove the lock part, there I need the `toggle` functionality. [I tried the below](http://jsfiddle.net/dQZfh/15/) but it didn't work.

```
  $("a.add_me").toggle(function(){
   $( this ).hide();
   this.src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/led24.de/led/16/lock-unlock-icon.png";
   }, function() { 
   $( this ).show();
   this.src = "http://media.videolectures.net/rel.1369417430//icons/lock.png";
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var unlock = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/led24.de/led/16/lock-unlock-icon.png';
var lock = 'http://media.videolectures.net/rel.1369417430//icons/lock.png';
$("a.add_me").data('lock', true).on("click", function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('lock')) {
        $this.find('img').attr('src', unlock); 
        $this.prev().prop('disabled', false);
        $this.data('lock', false);
    } else {
        $this.find('img').attr('src', lock);
        $this.prev().prop('disabled', true);
        $this.data('lock', true);
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dQZfh/17/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/dQZfh/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if($( this ).find('img').hasClass('unlock_image')){
    $( this ).find('img').removeClass('unlock_image').addClass('lock_image');
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/led24.de/led/16/lock-unlock-icon.png');
    }
    else{
         $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://media.videolectures.net/rel.1369417430//icons/lock.png');
         $( this ).find('img').removeClass('lock_image').addClass('unlock_image');
    };
```